# 'Hide' instead of 'mute' glyphs with box_select tool in Bokeh 1.4.0

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

I'm looking for a way to change the property of the 'box_select' tool from Bokeh.

## What it does

When selecting points (glyphs) with the box selection tool (same for the lasso selection tool), the default behavior of Bokeh is the following [default behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFbIz.png). To summarize, when data is shared between graphs (common data source, e.g. ColumnDataSource), if you select these data with the tool, the ones selected keep their color and alpha, but all the other non-selected ones get *'muted'* (the become default blue with a low alpha). This behavior by default also affects every graph where the data selected is used (which is cool).

## What I would like it to do

When doing what is described above, I would like all the unselected data points to disappear for every graph. To become 'hidden', [in the same way as this example from the doc](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/1.3.2/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html), except not for *legends*, but for *selections*.

It seems that the relevant information in the doc should be located here : https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/selections.html?highlight=union%20renderers#bokeh.models.selections.UnionRenderers

However, I did not see which property to change (default 'mute' -> custom 'hide') to achieve this goal.

Thanks everyone beforehand for your assistance.

Comment: For the future: Please don't put your tags in the title, that's what tags are for ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a way around this issue is to use something like :

```
plot.circle(source=cds, x='x', y='y', color='red', alpha=0.01, nonselection_alpha=0)
```

As presented in this part of the doc :

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#selected-and-unselected-glyphs